# Datatorrent -Apex - Unable to launch application

Tags: hadoop, installation, bigdata, apache-storm

I did a quick installation of Apex Datatorrent on my cluster few days back. Today i am trying to run wordcount job on datatorrent but while launching application it is giving me below error.

> LICENSE_MANAGER_ERROR error
>   Cannot get license info from agent

I can see that license is still valid.

> LICENSE_EXPIRATION warning
>   License will expire in 13 day(s)

How do I start license manager?

Answer (score 1):

More info on how to trouble shoot the license agent can be found here:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/apex-dev/tZmEWzgjuW0

There is also RTS 3.0 just around the corner that will do away with the license agent.